# update code on a remote server with github

Tags: github, raspberry-pi, continuous-integration

I got an application running on a raspberry server. I use git and github for versioning. I would like to update code on the server when a pull request is accepted on the main branch.

What kind of tool can I use ? I try https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action with no succeed to connec to the server. Any other idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On GitHub side, you can trigger on accepted PR:4

- a GitHub action (like the one you mention)
- a WebHook (which sends a JSON payload to an IP of your choice)

In both instance, that supposes your  raspberry server:

- has an IP accessible from GitHub
- a port opened (22 for SSH, 80 or 443 for HTTP(S))

You can use a [curl-based GitHub action](https://github.com/simonw/playing-with-actions/blob/master/.github/workflows/latest-curl.yml) to test out a `curl -v telnet://<your.IP>:22` and see if the IP:port is accessible from GitHub.